# How to compile using g++ with -std=c++11 flag?

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors

I'm trying to setup my computer (windows 10) for compiling c++ 11. I have written a simple hello world program which I can compile using
`g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe -static-libgcc`
but when I change command to allow c++ 11 like this
`g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe -static-libgcc -std=c++11`
I get rather unexpected (for me) error

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdio:42:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:46,
                 from helloworld.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:788:34: error: '__off64_t' does not name a type
 typedef union { __int64 __value; __off64_t __offset; } fpos_t;
                                  ^~~~~~~~~
```

As for background info, i use g++ 6.3.0 (at least that is what i see after typing `g++ --veriosn` into cmd).
What should I do to fix this? (to be able to compile)

Comment: I don't have *MinGW* installed in default location, but *c:\mingw\include\stdio.h* path seems a bit suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I use the most rude way, just add `#include "sys/types.h"` in `stdio.h`